# Is $\{ r \mapsto X_{r} \text{ is continuous for all } s < t \} \in \sigma(X_s : s \leq t)$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

If $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a stochastic process, is $\{ r \mapsto X_{r} \text{ is continuous for all } $s < t$ \} \in \sigma(X_s : s \leq t)$?

I'm particularly interested in the case where $X_t$ is a cadlag process (that is, $t \mapsto X_t$ is right-continuous and its left limits exist).

Comment: You have to be more precise, $X_s$ is just a random variable for fixed $s$.

Answer (score 1):

Without the restriction, the answer is clearly negative: consider $X_t=\mathbf 1_{t-T\in\mathbb Q}$ where $T$ is a nonnegative random time with an absolutely continuous distribution.